# Checking for None when accessing nested attributes

Tags: python, attributes

I am currently implementing an ORM that stores data defined in an XSD handled with a DOM generated by [PyXB](https://github.com/pabigot/pyxb).
Many of the respective elements contain sub-elements and so forth, which each have a `minOccurs=0` and thus may resolve to None in the DOM.
Hence when accessing some element hierarchy containing optional elements I now face the problem whether to use:

```
with suppress(AttributeError):
    wanted_subelement = root.subelement.sub_subelement.wanted_subelement
```

or rather

```
if root.subelement is not None:
    if root.subelement.sub_subelement is not None:
        wanted_subelement = root.subelement.sub_subelement.wanted_subelement
```

While both styles work perfectly fine, which is preferable? (I am not Dutch, btw.)

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
if root.subelement and root.subelement.sub_subelement:
    wanted_subelement = root.subelement.sub_subelement.wanted_subelement
```

The if statement evaluates None as False and will check from left to right. So if the first element evaluates to false it will not try to access the second one.

Comment: Yes, your're right. But this way the expression may easily exceed 80 characters in length.

Answer (score 1):

If you have quite a few such lookups to perform, better to wrap this up in a more generic lookup function:

```
# use a sentinel object distinct from None 
# in case None is a valid value for an attribute
notfound = object()

# resolve a python attribute path
# - mostly, a `getattr` that supports
#   arbitrary sub-attributes lookups    
def resolve(element, path):
    parts = path.split(".")
    while parts:
       next, parts = parts[0], parts[1:]
       element = getattr(element, next, notfound)
       if element is notfound:
           break
    return element

# just to test the whole thing    
class Element(object):
   def __init__(self, name, **attribs):
       self.name = name
       for k, v in attribs.items():
           setattr(self, k, v)

e  = Element(
    "top",
    sub1=Element("sub1"),
    nested1=Element(
        "nested1", 
        nested2=Element(
            "nested2", 
             nested3=Element("nested3")
             )
        )
    )


tests = [
    "notthere",
    "does.not.exists",
    "sub1",
    "sub1.sub2",
    "nested1",
    "nested1.nested2",
    "nested1.nested2.nested3"
    ]

for path in tests:
    sub = resolve(e, path)
    if sub is notfound:
        print "%s : not found" % path
    else:
        print "%s : %s" % (path, sub.name)
```

Comment: I actually do have a lot of these access checks to perform. However, accessing the attributes via a stringified version of the path would probably make my code less readable and error-prone and would reduce the PyXB DOM models to absurdity.

Comment: @RichardNeumann as far as I'm concerned I'd find the "stringified path" resolution much more readable than long lines of `if elt.attr and elt.attr.subattr and elt.attr.subattr.subsubattr` etc,  but that's possibly subjective. Wrt/ absurdity, I'd say that a DOM model that doesn't support path expression lookups _is_ an absurdity, but here again YMMV ;)